# Tagging images like facebook using wxpython

Tags: tags, wxpython

How can i go about creating a tagging images function like similar to facebook? The idea I have is I want the user to be able to click on areas of the image in order to tag it. I want to store the co-ordinates the user clicks as well. I'm using wxWidgets with Python2.7.2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use something like wx.GetMousePosition to grab the coordinates. I would probably bind to wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN or wx.EVT_LEFT_UP. There's a [wiki page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ClientCoordinates) on the wxPython site with more information. Or you might find reading the [docs](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MouseEvent-class.html) helpful.

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285878/how-to-convert-wx-getmouseposition-co-ordinates-to-fit-in-a-dc