# How to convert wx.GetMousePosition co-ordinates to fit in a DC

Tags: python, image, user-interface, wxpython

I'm creating a photo viewer which the user can use to tag images like in facebook. Once the image is clicked on to be tagged, I use wx.GetMousePosition to find the position where the mouse was clicked on the image.I then create a wx.MemoryDC of the image which the user has tagged so that I can draw the tags on the image using dc.DrawRectangle.

Below is the code for drawing onto the image:
I'm using wxPython by the way

```
        W=495 #Position of mouse (y)
        H=205 #Position of mouse (x)
        dc = wx.MemoryDC()
        dc.SelectObject(bitImg)#name of bitmap image
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#FF0000'))

        #dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#aaffff'))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.TRANSPARENT_BRUSH)
        dc.DrawRectangle(W, H, 20, 20)# Drawing the rectangle using the W and H 
                                      # for the position
        dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
```

The first two lines are the X and Y co-ordinates which I receive from wx.GetMousePosition. This is the position of a tag on one of the images. These points W and H however do not show on the image when I draw the rectangle as they are too big and don't show on the screen. If I set W and H both to 90 it will draw a small square on the image.

So how can I convert these wx.GetMousePosition co-ordinates so that they fit in the 'dc'? or any other suggestions on getting the mouse co-ordinates?

Comment: @Mike Driscoll please you at this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wx.GetMousePosition` will return co-ordinates for the mouse on the screen which will either be in the wrong place in the image, or likely off the edge of the image as you're seeing.

One way you can convert these co-ordinates is to pass them to the panel the image is on, `panel.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())` which will convert them into co-ordinates relative to the top left of the panel.